# The problem of regex strings containing special characters in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string: "`s = string.charAt (0) == 'd'`"
I want to retrieve a tuple of `('0', 'd')`
I have used: `re.search(r "\ ((. ?) \) == '(.?)' && "," string.charAt (0) == 'd' ")`
I checked the **s** variable when printed as `"\\ ((.?) \\) == '(.?) '&& "`
How do I fix it?

Comment: What do you want returned if the string were `"s = string.charAt (12) != 'abc' + 'def'"`? You need to state the rule for identifying the characters you wish to extract.

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
\((\d+)\).*?'(\w+)'
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`\(`** - Matches a `(` literally.
- **`(\d+)`** - Represents the first capturing group matching digits one or more times.
- **`\)`** - Matches a `)` literally.
- **`.*?`** - **Lazily** matches everything except a new-line.
- **`'(\w+)'`** - Represents second capturing group matching `'` along with any word character(`[0-9a-zA-Z_]`) one or more times.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

#### Regex Demo

```
import re
regex = r"\((\d+)\).*?'(\w+)'"
test_str = "s = string.charAt (0) == 'd'"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
# Output: [('0', 'd')]
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/r1CE-gSyP)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\((.*?)\)\s*==\s*'(.*?)'
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/L9nALV/2). The first variable is captured inside Group 1 and the second variable is inside Group 2.

Python code:

```
import re
string = "s = string.charAt (0) == 'd'"
match_data = re.search(r"\((.*?)\)\s*==\s*'(.*?)'", string)
if match_data:
    print(f"Var#1 = {match_data.group(1)}\nVar#2 = {match_data.group(2)}")
```

Output:

```
Var#1 = 0
Var#2 = d
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression should be `".*\((.?)\) .* '(.?)\'"`.  This will get both the character inside the parenthesis and then the character inside the single quotes.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = " s = string.charAt (0) == 'd'"
>>> m = re.search(r".*\((.?)\) .* '(.?)'", s)
>>> m.groups()
('0', 'd')
```

Answer (score -1):

**Thanks everyone for the very helpful answer. My problem has been solved ^^**